spring boot Questions about the efficient bounds of pessimistic locking
I am creating a reservation service with spring boot and used pessimistic lock (PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).
When I pressed reserve, I used PESSIMISTIC_WRITE to check if there was a reservation space, but it was pointed out that the lock setting range was not efficient.
I did a search and it seems like everyone is setting PESSIMISTIC_WRITE when checking to see if there are any reservation spaces left, but I don't know what the problem is.
Did you receive that criticism because you were counting the number of remaining digits with the select count?
If the use of PESSIMISTIC_WRITE is not appropriate due to select count queries, can it be improved by changing the DB design?
If not, I'm really curious what the problem is...!!
---
spring boot로 예약 서비스를 만들고 있어 비관적 락(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)을 사용하였습니다.
예약하기를 누를 때 예약 빈 자리가 있는지 확인할 때 PESSIMISTIC_WRITE을 걸었는데 범위가 효율적이지 않다고 지적을 받았습니다.
검색을 해보았는데 다들 예약 자리가 남아있는지 확인할 때 PESSIMISTIC_WRITE을 걸어 놓는 것 같은데 뭐가 문제인지 모르겠습니다.
select count로 남은 자리 개수를 세는 거여서 그런 지적을 받았던 것일까요?
select count 쿼리 때문에 PESSIMISTIC_WRITE 사용이 적절하지 못하다면 DB 설계를 바꿔 개선할 수 있을까요?
그게 아니면 어떤 문제인지 정말 궁금합니다...!!
@Service
public class AppointmentsService {

    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<?> createReservation(AppointmentsDTO appointmentsDTO, String userId) {
             //

            // Check availability - pessimistic lock
            if (!isTimeSlotAvailable(appointmentsDTO.getHospitalId(), appointmentsDTO.getDate(), appointmentsDTO.getTime())) {
                throw new CustomValidationException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), Reservation not possible);
            }

            
            appointmentsRepository.save(convertDtoToEntity(appointmentsDTO, userId));
    }
}

//Check availability method - pessimistic lock
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    boolean isTimeSlotAvailable(String hospitalId, LocalDate date, LocalTime time) {
        //int seat = availableTimeService.calculateAvailableSlots(hospitalId, date, time);
        int seat = 3 - appointmentsRepository.countAppointmentsForTimeSlot(hospitalId, date, time);
        if(seat > 0) //
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

@Repository
public interface AppointmentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointments, String> {

    @Query(SELECT COUNT(a) FROM Appointments a WHERE a.hospital.businessId = :businessId AND a.appointmentDate = :appointmentDate AND a.appointmentTime = :appointmentTime)
    int countByHospital_BusinessIdAndAppointmentDateAndAppointmentTime(@Param(businessId) String businessId, @Param(appointmentDate) LocalDate appointmentDate, @Param(appointmentTime) LocalTime appointmentTime);

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) 
    @QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = javax.persistence.lock.timeout, value = 5000) })
    @Query(SELECT COUNT(a) FROM Appointments a WHERE a.hospital.businessId = :businessId AND a.appointmentDate = :appointmentDate AND a.appointmentTime = :startTime)
    int countAppointmentsForTimeSlot(@Param(businessId) String businessId,
                                     @Param(appointmentDate) LocalDate appointmentDate,
                                     @Param(startTime) LocalTime startTime);
}

Concurrency control seems to be working, but I would appreciate it if you could let me know if the lock range is set properly.
